# Accessing data from different properties in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have different properties in Google Analytics account. One for the main website and other for the android app. I am currently using Google Embed API in Javascript to access the data from the first property. Now I want to access the data from the second property as well. Is there any way to access the data from the other property in the same code.

I'm new to Google Analytics. It would be really helpful if you could also provide any reference material on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to the Embed API for Android, but there are Java client libraries for querying the various Google APIs that should do what you need.

This page lists all the client libraries for various languages and should be useful to you in general:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The solution was fairly simple. All I had to do was to change the ID in the Query to the value of the ID of the account I wanted to use and the request was sent corresponding account.